# How to map a table column with another table column in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jsp

I am creating a web app in hibernate with spring rest and i am stuck between two tables. I want to map a table column with another table column. I have done it in jsp but now i want to do in hibernate. I am fetching author_id from alert table and then i want to fetch profile pic of that author id from user_table.

Jsp code:

```
<%

String sql = "select author_id from alert where id=2";
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next()){
String aid = rs.getString("author_id");
String sql1 = "select profile_img from user_table where id='"+aid+"'";
Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery(sql1);
while(rs1.next()){
String image_name = rs1.getString("profile_img");
}
}
%>
```

I want to do it in hibernate.Here is my Alert class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="alert")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Alert implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private long id;

@Column(name="author_id")
private long author_id;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public long getAuthor_id() {
    return author_id;
}

public void setAuthor_id(long author_id) {
    this.author_id = author_id;
}
```

Here is my User class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_table")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class User implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private long id;

@Column(name="profile_img")
private String img_name;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getImg_name() {
    return img_name;
}

public void setImg_name(String img_name) {
    this.img_name = img_name;
}
}
```

Here is my DAO class:

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

Session session = null;
Transaction tx = null;

public User getUserById(long id) throws Exception {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    User user = (User) session.load(User.class, new Long(id));
    tx = session.getTransaction();
    session.beginTransaction();
    tx.commit();
    return user;
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public List<Alert> getAlertById(long id) throws Exception {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Alert.class);
    cr.add(Restrictions.eq("alert_viewer_id", id));
    List alert = cr.list();
    tx = session.getTransaction();
    session.beginTransaction();
    tx.commit();
    return alert;
}
```

Please help me i am stuck in hibernate .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you work with an ORM, you need to think in terms of objects and their relationships with each other rather than database tables, columns, foreign keys, etc.  Although you can map tables and columns directly to classes and fields, you will not get much mileage by doing so because the true purpose of viewing your application data as an object graph and using an ORM to manage that graph will be defeated.

If you change:

```
@Column(name="author_id")
private long author_id;

public long getAuthor_id() { return author_id; }

public void setAuthor_id(long author_id) { this.author_id = author_id; }
```

to:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private User author;

public User getAuthor() { return author; }

public void setAuthor(User author) { this.author = author; }
```

anytime you have an `Alert` object, you can simply call `getAuthor` on it to get a `User` object back that you can work with directly.

This change does not require any change to your database.

Comment: where the object of alert will be created ?

Comment: In your SQL code above, you have an alert ID.  You fire a SQL query to get the author ID for the alert with that ID.  Then you fire a second SQL query to get the profile image of the user with the ID retrieved earlier.  With Hibernate, if you do `session.createCriteria(Alert.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id", alertId).uniqueResult()`, you will get an `Alert` object with the id equal to the value of `alertId` variable.  This is equivalent to your first query above.  Then you simply do `alert.getAuthor().getImg_name()` on the `alert` object.

Comment: bro please change my code and post i am unable to understand because i am new in hibernate

Comment: And in User class i dont need to add or change anything?

Comment: where i will write alert.getAuthor().getImg_name()?

Comment: The line `String image_name = rs1.getString("profile_img")` will change to `String image_name = alert.getAuthor().getImg_name()`, provided you have obtained the `alert` object correctly.  I cannot tell you more because you have posted only a part of the code.  Also note that users here will help you solve specific problems with your code but will not write the code for you, even if you are new to a technology.  If you are new to the technology, read online tutorials and try out samples to get a good understanding.  Otherwise, you risk getting downvoted and even banned from asking questions.

Comment: one last thing i want to ask u is in my angular i am getting image name using  $scope.data = userFactory.alert[0].authorId.img;    ..Because the reslut is coming in list so i am using alert[0] .. but i want all author id images at once

Comment: I don't know AngularJS too much.  That could be a separate question to post for someone with AngularJS expertise to take a look at.